# How to override shipping-address/form.html with my theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to override the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/form.html` using my theme, but I can't find which path is correct. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/form.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please place the file form.html inside your theme like this in path -

"app/design/frontend/Ced/ced_2k18/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/form.html"

Please do let know if it helps or not.

Please refer the below image for clear image structure in phpstorm [image]